# Unable to import PIL through PHP

Tags: php, python, linux, pip, importerror

```
<?php
echo exec("python txt_img.py admin 2>&1");
highlight_file(__FILE__);
?>
```

The php is running with no issues in the server,but when I access the php through browser it's showing the error ImportError: No module named 'PIL'.
The python code is also running without any issues in the server.

```
# desired size
import random
import sys
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
img = random.randint(1,10)
image = Image.open(str(img)+'.jpeg')

# initialise the drawing context with
# the image object as background

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf',100) 
# starting position of the message
(x, y) = (100,70)
name = sys.argv[1]  
color = 'rgb(0,0,0)'
draw.text((x, y), "Welcome "+name, fill=color,font=font)
# save the edited image
img= random.randint(1,10)
img = "greet_"+str(img)+".jpeg"
image.save(img)
print(img)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: but the python script works fine independently?

Comment: @gavin yes,the python script works fine

Comment: I'd suggest you `import pip` and add a try-catch to `pip.main(['install', 'pillow'])` before the imports, maybe just on the first run; maybe it's installed currently for another user or root or environment

Comment: The directory '/var/www/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag. 

I got this error

Comment: solved the proble with : sudo -H pip install pillow
Thanks @gavin

Comment: accept an answer to your question for others who might be having similar issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PIL must be installed for current user or for root, which can be achieved by either installing it through the script itself, using `subprocess` or by

```
sudo pip install pillow
```

For earlier versions of pip (<10) `pip.main(['install', package])` could also work but using subprocess is a safer bet.

This is just a hacky way to do this, there must be better ways around this.